# Unable to download external jars in to Artifactory

Tags: maven, maven-2, repository, artifactory

I am using Jfrog's Artifactory and i have included repo1.maven.org/maven2 as a remote repository but when i request for a particular artifact from my IDE, the artifactory doesnt download it to the cache from the remote server? any idea what i am missing here?

Edit:

the artifactory.log is displaying the below error message

```
2012-01-09 13:08:10,814 [pool-1-thread-15] [INFO ] (o.a.c.h.HttpMethodDirector:445) - Retrying request

2012-01-09 13:08:11,814 [pool-1-thread-15] [WARN ] (o.a.r.RemoteRepoBase:323) - jfrog-libs: Error in getting information for 'opensymphony/quartz/1.6.5/quartz-1.6.5.pom' (Failed retrieving resource from http://repo.jfrog.org/artifactory/libs-release-local/opensymphony/quartz/1.6.5/quartz-1.6.5.pom: Connection refused: connect).

2012-01-09 13:08:13,408 [pool-1-thread-16] [INFO ] (o.a.c.h.HttpMethodDirector:439) - I/O exception (java.net.ConnectException) caught when processing request: Connection refused: connect
```

below is part of the project's pom.xml

```
<distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>COMPANY_INTERNAL</id>
            <name>COMPANY internal repository</name>
            <url>http://artifactoryserver:18081/artifactory/company</url>
        </repository>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>COMPANY_INTERNAL_SNAPSHOTS</id>
            <name>companyinternal snapshot repository</name>
            <url>http://artifactoryserver:18081/artifactory/company</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>COMPANY_PUBLIC</id>
            <name>COMPANY internal and external repository</name>
            <url>http://artifactoryserver:18081/artifactory/repo</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>COMPANY_PLUGINS</id>
            <name>Maven Plugin Repository</name>
            <url>http://artifactoryserver:18081/artifactory/plugins-releases</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
```

Screenshots

1) [Local Repository](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oe46h.gif) 
2)[Remote Repository](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t4EEr.gif)
3) [Virtual Repository](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMwZA.gif)
4) [Repository Browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Ytqe.gif)

Also including the request.log contents below,

```
20120110094113|3735|REQUEST|SERVER_IP_HIDDEN|non_authenticated_user|GET|/repo/com/vividsolutions/jts/1.12-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml|HTTP/1.1|200|311
20120110094114|63|REQUEST|SERVER_IP_HIDDEN|non_authenticated_user|GET|/repo/com/vividsolutions/jts/1.12-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml.sha1|HTTP/1.1|200|40
20120110094114|16|REQUEST|SERVER_IP_HIDDEN|non_authenticated_user|GET|/repo/com/vividsolutions/jts/1.12-SNAPSHOT/jts-1.12-SNAPSHOT.pom|HTTP/1.1|304|461
20120110094116|2422|REQUEST|SERVER_IP_HIDDEN|non_authenticated_user|GET|/repo/org/hibernatespatial/hibernate-spatial/1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml|HTTP/1.1|200|326
20120110094116|16|REQUEST|SERVER_IP_HIDDEN|non_authenticated_user|GET|/repo/org/hibernatespatial/hibernate-spatial/1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml.sha1|HTTP/1.1|200|40
20120110094116|0|REQUEST|SERVER_IP_HIDDEN|non_authenticated_user|GET|/repo/org/hibernatespatial/hibernate-spatial/1.0-SNAPSHOT/hibernate-spatial-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom|HTTP/1.1|304|1761
20120110094117|0|REQUEST|SERVER_IP_HIDDEN|admin|GET|/webapp/systemlogs.html|HTTP/1.1|200|0
20120110094118|2406|REQUEST|SERVER_IP_HIDDEN|non_authenticated_user|GET|/repo/org/hibernatespatial/hibernate-spatial-maven/1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml|HTTP/1.1|200|332
20120110094118|15|REQUEST|SERVER_IP_HIDDEN|non_authenticated_user|GET|/repo/org/hibernatespatial/hibernate-spatial-maven/1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml.sha1|HTTP/1.1|200|40
20120110094119|16|REQUEST|SERVER_IP_HIDDEN|non_authenticated_user|GET|/repo/org/hibernatespatial/hibernate-spatial-maven/1.0-SNAPSHOT/hibernate-spatial-maven-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom|HTTP/1.1|304|8144
20120110094121|2281|REQUEST|SERVER_IP_HIDDEN|non_authenticated_user|GET|/repo/company/companylib_service_hibernate/5.0.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml|HTTP/1.1|200|317 
20120110094121|16|REQUEST|SERVER_IP_HIDDEN|non_authenticated_user|GET|/repo/company/companylib_service_hibernate/5.0.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml.sha1|HTTP/1.1|200|40
20120110094121|0|REQUEST|SERVER_IP_HIDDEN|non_authenticated_user|GET|/repo/company/companylib_service_hibernate/5.0.0-SNAPSHOT/companylib_service_hibernate-5.0.0-SNAPSHOT.pom|HTTP/1.1|304|4224
20120110094123|2297|REQUEST|SERVER_IP_HIDDEN|non_authenticated_user|GET|/repo/company/companylib_domain_parent/5.0.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml|HTTP/1.1|200|313
20120110094123|16|REQUEST|SERVER_IP_HIDDEN|non_authenticated_user|GET|/repo/company/companylib_domain_parent/5.0.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml.sha1|HTTP/1.1|200|40
20120110094123|0|REQUEST|SERVER_IP_HIDDEN|non_authenticated_user|GET|/repo/company/companylib_domain_parent/5.0.0-SNAPSHOT/companylib_domain_parent-5.0.0-SNAPSHOT.pom|HTTP/1.1|304|13997
20120110094126|2406|REQUEST|SERVER_IP_HIDDEN|non_authenticated_user|GET|/repo/org/hibernatespatial/hibernate-spatial-oracle/1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml|HTTP/1.1|200|333
20120110094126|16|REQUEST|SERVER_IP_HIDDEN|non_authenticated_user|GET|/repo/org/hibernatespatial/hibernate-spatial-oracle/1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml.sha1|HTTP/1.1|200|40
20120110094126|0|REQUEST|SERVER_IP_HIDDEN|non_authenticated_user|GET|/repo/org/hibernatespatial/hibernate-spatial-oracle/1.0-SNAPSHOT/hibernate-spatial-oracle-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom|HTTP/1.1|304|1779
20120110094127|15|REQUEST|SERVER_IP_HIDDEN|non_authenticated_user|GET|/repo/org/hibernatespatial/hibernate-spatial/1.0-SNAPSHOT/hibernate-spatial-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar|HTTP/1.1|304|77589
20120110094127|16|REQUEST|SERVER_IP_HIDDEN|non_authenticated_user|GET|/repo/com/vividsolutions/jts/1.12-SNAPSHOT/jts-1.12-SNAPSHOT.jar|HTTP/1.1|304|755797
20120110094127|0|REQUEST|SERVER_IP_HIDDEN|non_authenticated_user|GET|/repo/company/companylib_service_hibernate/5.0.0-SNAPSHOT/companylib_service_hibernate-5.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar|HTTP/1.1|304|77835
20120110094127|15|REQUEST|SERVER_IP_HIDDEN|non_authenticated_user|GET|/repo/org/hibernatespatial/hibernate-spatial-oracle/1.0-SNAPSHOT/hibernate-spatial-oracle-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar|HTTP/1.1|304|62943
20120110094127|15|REQUEST|SERVER_IP_HIDDEN|admin|GET|/webapp/systemlogs.html|HTTP/1.1|200|0
20120110094137|0|REQUEST|SERVER_IP_HIDDEN|admin|GET|/webapp/systemlogs.html|HTTP/1.1|200|0
```

Comment: Are you sure your build is trying to use your Artifactory server as a repo or is it going straight to Central instead?  You can use mirrors in your settings.xml to mirror Central and force your build to go to Artifactory for all artifacts.

Comment: so basically i have pom.xml in which repositoy, pluginRepository  all point to the artifactory server. what do you mean by "or is it going straight to Central instead" ?

Comment: There are a number of factors that may be in effect here.
What IDE are you using? What dependency management integration are you using?
You can start by taking a look into Artifactory's request log (can be found in $ARTIFACTORY_HOME/logs/request.log) to see if your request reaches the repository.

Comment: I dont understand why it is throwing connection refused error and why it is not trying to connect to repo1.maven.org/maven2

Comment: Which one of Artifactory's repositories do you point your request at?

Comment: A connection refused error means that your instance is experiencing connectivity issues with JFrog's public instance (repo.jfrog.org).

Comment: please see the updated question for the repository settings, as you can see everything is pointed to the artifactory and not any external server.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6559/discussion-between-noamt-and-sixthstring)

Comment: The maven central repo is in maven's super pom so unless you mask it with a mirror (or make it inaccessible via hosts/proxy) your local build will always try to fetch an artifact from there as a last resort.  This means, if your Artifactory configuration is messed up in some way, and isn't acting as a proxy to central, then your project will still build and you won't see that artifact being cached by Artifactory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see in the response.log you've attached that Artifactory returns an [HTTP 304 (Not Modified)](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3.5) response status (second column to the right of the entry) for the requested snapshot artifacts.

This means that the requested **artifact already exists in your local machine's cache** and that no newer version could be found in Artifactory.

Whatever tool you're using requested this artifact with a conditional headers based on the local version's last modified time (namely, ["Last-Modified"](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.29) and ["If-Modified-Since"](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.25)); since no newer version could be found, re-downloading the same artifact is pointless, which is why you don't see it in Artifactory's cache repo.

Comment: thank you noamt. I cleared my local .m2 folder and it downloaded everything again this time.

Answer (score 2):

Does your company's network require you use a proxy to access the external internet?  If so, you need to set that proxy in Artifactory's Admin/Configuration/Proxies screen, then for each external repo Artifactory is acting as a proxy for, you need to specify this proxy on the repo's "Advanced Settings" tab.

Comment: Also, you should be able to browse to http://repo.jfrog.org/artifactory/libs-release-local/opensymphony/quartz/1.6.5/ - but that directory does not exist.  If you back up to just http://repo.jfrog.org/artifactory/libs-releases-local/ you'll see there is no "opensymphony" directory.  You're looking in the wrong repo for that artifact.  If you go to http://search.maven.org and search for quartz, you'll see it's in central, not jfrog's repo.

Comment: there is no proxy in the network. Also i have repo1.maven.org/maven2 in the "remote-repos" list (virtual repository).

Comment: Then you need to look at how the "repo" virtual repository is configured - which remote/local/virtual repos it consists of and the order of resolution.  If jfrog's repo is on this list, move it down - below central - to see if it will resolve quartz successfully.

Comment: repo is a global aggregation of all repositories configured, which is why I suspect that the client is somehow referencing the wrong repository (hence my request for the contents of the request.log)

Comment: I have added the screenshots of the Artifactory. I could not see any global repository named "repo" I am not sure if that is any system's default global repository or user created one.

Comment: Repo is an internally configured repository; usable but not configurable by users.

Comment: @tdrury +1 We are using a proxy and it was configured, just not in the advanced tab per repo. I was getting unknown host exceptions all the time. It's very counter intuitive to have to select the proxy in the advanced tab again.

Answer (score 0):

I had a fun experience with this same type of error today, but it was on a GET request only (no DEPLOY like the original poster).

In my case the user's ~/.m2/settings.xml was taken from a template file that had:

```
<server>
    <id>${server-id}</id>
    <username>a-valid-username</username>
    <password>valid-pass</password>
</server>
```

Later in the settings.xml template that they had copied and modified with their credentials was the repository url.

This caused the behavior that they could hit the server and make the request, but it would never try to authenticate.

They got the authentication denied message, and a "non_authenticated_user" showed up as making a GET request in the request.log.

Once we replaced the bogus/undefined ${server-id} with the server's actual id it started working.